# How to improve Ubuntu 14.04 LTS boot time on a laptop?

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on my lenevo G505S laptop. As it, there are many complaints of this laptop not being able to handle ubuntu properly. I have some of mine.

Every time I turn on my laptop, the screen goes purple for about 10 seconds and then black for about another 20 s. And so overall booting time is a little more than half a minute. Which is kinda sad.

I'm assuming something is going on before the computer starts up?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly is going on in PC while it is booting but you can reduce boot time with program called e4rat. It worked for me. But last time I used it I were using Ubuntu 12.10. So I don't know that does e4rat work with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the HDD version of the laptop this could be a IO thing, as im aware the HDD only has 5400rpm.

You might as well check the autostart applications and remove unnecessary software.

Since unity is probably demanding to your hardware, you could try the slim XCFE , LXDE or any other performance oriented desktop environment.

There are also ubuntu based distros which come with those out of the box.

Xubuntu http://xubuntu.org
Lubuntu http://lubuntu.net

You can also install and replace the desktop environment from the commandline/window manager/packet manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard spinning harddrive, E4rat can improve the loading of your system. Link to how to install it-

http://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/?PageSpeed=noscript

Also, if you are not using btrfs, this can delay your bootup by several seconds. You can safely uninstall btrfs-tools.

```
sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools
```